# copy-item working for subdirectories only second time script is run

Tags: powershell-5.0

I have a script that I am using to backup files.  For some reason, it is only copying the files and dir of the sub-folder the second time the script runs.  The error message is

> "Container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item".

I am searching for this error and they say I am copying a file onto the same file name, but this is a subdir that doesn't even get created the first time the script runs.  The destination folder is empty the first time I run this. Any ideas?

The source dir looks like this:

```
 \\DRIVE01\Svcs
              \Credential
                     \Forms
                         file and dir list   #this dir level doesn't get copied the first time, but the files do
```

This is what the toLoc looks like after the first execution:

```
      me\Documents\2018\powershellFiles\toLoc
              \Credential
                     \Forms
                         file list   #the first time the files get copied without the dirs at this level
```

This is my script:

```
function CopyFileToFolderUNC($SourcePath, $DestinationPath){
         Copy-Item -Path $SourcePath/* -Destination $DestinationPath #Copy-Item -Path source -Destination target  -Recurse -Force 
}


#################start here##################################

$tempSource = @("\\DRIVE01\Svcs\Credentialing\FORMS") #eventually will have list of more than one here
$ToLocation = "C:\Users\me\Documents\2018 \powershellFiles\toLoc\Credentialing\FORMS\"  #this will eventually be array with multiple in it

for($i=0; $i -lt ($tempSource.Length); $i++) {
   CopyFileToFolderUNC $tempSource[$i] $ToLocation
}
```

Before I switched to a for loop from a foreach, I thought it was working for the subdirs in the toLoc.  I need a for loop because it will be easier to deal with arrays for the source and destination dir strings which will be next.

Comment: facing same issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use robocopy.

robocopy c:\fold1 c:\fold2 /s